# how to specify a custom stylesheet in scalate ssp

Tags: css, scala, scalate

How to specify a custom stylesheet (external) to a SSP template (Scala Server Pages) in Scalate?

I tried specifying the html linking in the `default.ssp` file as follows.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
        <%= unescape(body) %>
   </body>
</html>
```

However the stylesheet is not served by Scalatra (Jetty Web Server). I tried inserting the script through `<%@include ..` as well. Still no luck.

The web page is served without any stylesheet!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `style.css` file as follows.

```
cd <YourProjectRoot>/src/main/webapp/
mkdir css
touch style.css
```

Create a style.css file inside a directory **css** which should be within the `webapp` directory, for the Scalatra to find out and serve the resource (stylesheet) appropriately.

**Note:** The folder should be named as `css` however the file can be named as anything.